# Web API and Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am working with back end written by another developer. I think he used Web API 2.0 and Entity Framework. Specifically I am having a problem with POST. Here is the code:

```
 public CL_CASE Post([FromBody]CL_CASE value)
    {......
```

I am testing it using Chrome's Advanced Rest Client. I am specifying a few parameters and clicking Send. The value I am getting is null. What might be causing that?

```
var response = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        withCredentials: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        params: '',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        url: url
    });
```

payload is an object with properties that match CL_CASE.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you can check.

First, are the parameters you are passing in the body of the post or on the query string? The attribute [FromBody] on the value argument passed into the Post method is telling the model binder to look in the body of the HTTP request for matching parameters.

It's also important that the parameters you are passing are being specified using the correct Content-Type. Are you using a Content-Type header? If not, the expectation is probably that you are using form encoding. If that's the case, you should be specifying your parameters in the body like this:

```
paramName1=paramValue&paramName2=paramValue
```

Be sure the case of the parameter matches the case used for the matching property in the CL_CASE class too. These can be different cases and still be matched if you are using the right ContractResolver.

Another thing to be sure of is that you are in fact choosing to POST instead of GET.

Are there any other attributes on the Post method in your controller? If there are, these could be throwing off the binding.

Comment: I am using Chrome's REST Client. I am using POST with Form parameters. After changing Content-Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded it seems to be working. Thanks

Comment: Now, I am trying to POST from my application and while value is not null anymore, I am not getting any data in value's properties. I have added my actual code.

Comment: hi @Mark, looking at your JavaScript above, it looks like you're putting two Content-Type headers in your request. You'll have to choose the way you are sending the data in the body. The first Content-Type header is application/json. This suggests that your data would be formatted like this:

Comment: `{ "paramName1": "value1", "paramName2": "value2" }`  assuming that the values are strings of course.

Comment: another gotcha here is that convention dictates that JSON parameters are camel cased while C# properties ( like you are trying to set your CL_CASE class) are usually Pascal cased. Since you are inheriting this code, the initial coder may have specified a camel case property ContractResolver. You can verify this by searching the code for the following:  `.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();`  if you don't see that in the code then that might be why you're parameters are not being model bound to the CL_CASE object.

Comment: Check out this link for a little more detail: [link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/25/asp-net-webapi-tip-3-camelcasing-json.aspx) and please don't forget to mark my answer as the answer if in fact it is.